# How to fix broken submodule config in git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm hitting this git error with sub module creation. I initial had a bad URL in the command, now any additional runs show this error. Any ideas on what is wrong?

```
$ git submodule add -f https://github.com/Shougo/vimproc.vim.git .vim/bundle/vimproc
Adding existing repo at '.vim/bundle/vimproc' to the index
fatal: Not a git repository: .vim/bundle/vimproc/../../../.git/modules/.vim/bundle/vimproc
Failed to add submodule '.vim/bundle/vimproc'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Maybe the submodules were added to the index. You should remove them from the index.

To remove a submodule completely, perform following steps:

1 remove these lines from `.git/config`

```
[submodule ".vim/bundle/vimproc"]
    url = https://github.com/Shougo/vimproc.vim.git
```

2 remove these lines from `.gitmodules`

```
[submodule ".vim/bundle/vimproc"]
    path = .vim/bundle/vimproc
    url = https://github.com/Shougo/vimproc.vim.git
```

3 remove the submodule directory

```
rm -rf .vim/bundle/vimproc
```

4 unstage submodule

```
git rm --cached .vim/bundle/vimproc
```

5 remove submodule directory in `.git/modules`

```
rm -rf .git/modules/.vim/bundle/vimproc
```

Finally, add the submodule again.

Comment: I confirmed I had run all of those steps before posting, and was still getting the error. Came back in the AM and it did work. I can't explain why it worked now but thanks.

Comment: For this to work for me I had to commit the changes in step #4 and then add the submodule back in another commit.

Comment: I had to stage the .gitmodules change in step 2 for this to work in my case.

Comment: Damn I hate git submodules